# socket TCP python file transfer - while True loop don't exit

Tags: python, sockets, client-server, break, file-transfer

I have made a socket TCP for file transfer using python. Everything is ok and I can receive the file from the server socket but the problem is that I can not exit the while True loop of client socket, even I put a break to exit this loop.

Someone can help me point out what is my mistake pls!
The loop run until to print "File Receiving..." and never exit, but I can receiver the file completely.
Thank you very much

Socket Client:

```
import socket
import os
import unicodedata
from tqdm import tqdm

SIZE = 1024*4
FILENAME = "xyz.bin"
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 8001
client_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcp_server_address = (HOST, PORT)
client_tcp.connect(tcp_server_address)
try:
    for i in range(1,11):
        texte = "PING\n"
        client_tcp.send(texte.encode())
        data=client_tcp.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print("Received:", str(data))

    texte = "ABC"
    client_tcp.send(texte.encode())
    data=client_tcp.recv(1024)
    print('Server: ', data.decode("utf8"))    

    with open(f"recv_{FILENAME}", "wb") as f:
        while True:
            data = client_tcp.recv(SIZE)
            if not data:
                #print("not data")
                break
            f.write(data)
        
            print("File Receiving...")

        print("Received:", str(data)) 
        client_tcp.send("Data received.".encode("utf-8"))           
f.close()
 
finally:            
    client_tcp.close()
    print("File Received")
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `with` will automatically close the file so no need of `f.close()`

Comment: yes, but it does not change anything, I still had the problem